# Cannot start a transaction for OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

Tags: java, sql-server

Two days ago when I executed the procedure through Java coding I got following error message:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot start a transaction for OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"

This is the snap of SQL procedure code

```
set @sql1='INSERT OPENROWSET(
    ''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'','D:\Users\media\workspacekepler\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp5\wtpwebapps\NPODownload\download\dump.mdb';
    'admin';'',Allocation) SELECT * FROM Allocation'
exec(@sql1)
```

Comment: It would be nice if you would [format your code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) in your question properly.

Comment: INSERT OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','D:\Users\media\workspacekepler.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp5\wtpwebapps\NPODownload\download\dump.mdb';'admin';'',Allocation) SELECT * FROM Allocation

Comment: This my code in mssql procedure

Comment: when using  JDBC connection to run an MSSQL prcedure through in command line am facing this issuse.